# failed to find required module enchant

Tags: python3, configure

I am installing the [OCRFeeder](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/OCRFeeder?action=show&redirect=OCRFeeder) in Debian.
To install the OCRFeeder I go to the root folder and execute the command:

```
sudo ./configure
```

The following error is shown in the terminal:

> checking python module: enchant... no configure: error: failed to find
>   required module enchant

I installed the enchant:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-enchant
```

However I am still receiving the same error.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried installing python2-enchant as well?

Answer (score 1):

just do:

```
sudo apt install ocrfeeder
```